# average previous time series in R

Tags: r, time-series

I'm wondering if there is an easy way to average over the previous 30 seconds of data in R when there may be more than one data point per second.

[image]

For instance, for the sample weight taken at 32 seconds, I want the mean of the concentrations recorded in the past 30 seconds, so the mean of `9, 10, 7, ..14,20, 18, 2)`. For the sample weight taken at 31 seconds,I want the mean of the concentrations recorded in the past 30 seconds, so the mean of `5, 9, 10, 7, .. 14,20, 18)`. It's technically not a rolling average over the 30 previous measurements because there can be more than one measurement per second.

I'd like to do this in R.

Comment: Data should *not* be presented as an image.  Use `dput`.  See [mcve] for more info on how to ask a question.

Answer (score 1):

**1) sqldf** Using `DF` below and 3 seconds join the last three seconds of data to each row of `DF` and then take the mean over them:

```
DF <- data.frame(time = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10), data = 1:10)

library(sqldf)
sqldf("select a.*, avg(b.data) mean 
       from DF a join DF b on b.time between a.time - 3 and a.time 
       group by a.rowid")
```

giving:

```
   time data mean
1     1    1  1.0
2     2    2  2.0
3     2    3  2.0
4     3    4  2.5
5     4    5  3.0
6     5    6  4.0
7     6    7  5.5
8     7    8  6.5
9     8    9  7.5
10   10   10  9.0
```

The first mean value is the mean(1) which is 1, the second and third mean values are mean(1:3) which is 2, the fourth mean value is mean(1:4) which is 2.5, the fifth mean value is mean(1:5) which is 3, the sixth mean value is mean(2:6) which is 4, the seventh mean value is mean(3:7) which is 5 and so on.

**2)** This 2nd solution uses no packages.  For each row of `DF` it finds the rows within 3 seconds back and takes the mean of their data:

```
Mean3 <- function(i) with(DF, mean(data[time <= time[i] & time >= time[i] - 3]))
cbind(DF, mean = sapply(1:nrow(DF), Mean3))
```

Answer (score 0):

The `rollapply` function should do the trick.

```
library(zoo)
rollapply(weight.vector, 30, mean)
```

Comment: Oops. I misunderstood the question. Why not just use a nested for loop? For each row, filter the table for rows within the last 30 seconds, and compute the mean.

Answer (score 0):

You can do (assuming your data is stored in a dataframe called `df`):

```
now <- 32
step <- 30
subsetData <- subset(df, time >= (now-step) & time < now)
average <- mean(subsetData$concentration)
```

And if you want to calculate the mean for at more time points, you can put this in a loop where you must adjust `now`

Answer (score 0):

My first idea would be to summarise the data so the value column would contain a list of all values.

```
test.data <- data.frame(t = 1:50 + rbinom(50, 30, 0.3), y=rnorm(50)) %>% arrange(t)
prep <- test.data %>% group_by(t) %>% summarise(vals = list(y))
wrk <- left_join(data.frame(t=1:max(test.data$t)), prep, by='t')
```

Unfortunately zoos `rollapply` would not work on such a data.frame.
For testing I was thinking to only use a window of 5 lines. 
I tried commands along: `rollapply(wrk, 5, function(z) mean(unlist(z)))`

But maybe someone else can fill in the missing bit of information.

Answer (score 0):

*This is sufficiently different that it warrants another answer.*

This should do what you're asking with no extra libraries needed.

It just loops through each row, filters based on that row's time, and computes the mean.

Don't fear a simple loop :)

```
count = 200 # dataset rows
windowTimespan = 30 # timespan of window

# first lets make some data
df = data.frame(
  # 200 random numbers from 0-99
  time = sort(floor(runif(count)*100)),
  concentration = runif(count),
  weight = runif(count)
)

# add placeholder column(s)
df$rollingMeanWeight = NA
df$rollingMeanConcentration = NA

# for each row
for (r in 1:nrow(df)) {
  # get the time in this row
  thisTime = df$time[r]
  # find all the rows within the acceptable timespan
  # note: figure out if you want < vs <=
  thisSubset = df[
    df$time < thisTime &  
    df$time >= thisTime-windowTimespan
  ,]
  # get the mean of the subset
  df$rollingMeanWeight[r] = mean(thisSubset$weight)
  df$rollingMeanConcentration[r] = mean(thisSubset$concentration)
}
```